# Splunk - regex extract fields from source

Tags: regex, splunk

I am trying to extract the job name , region from Splunk source using regex .

Below is the format of my sample source :

```
/home/app/abc/logs/20200817/job_DAILY_HR_REPORT_44414_USA_log
```

With the below , I am able to extract job name :

```
(?<logdir>\/[\W\w]+\/[\W\w]+\/)(?<date>[^\/]+)\/job_(?<jobname>.+)_\d+
```

Here is the match so far :

```
Full match  0-53    /home/app/abc/logs/20200817/job_DAILY_HR_REPORT_44414
Group `logdir`  0-19    /home/app/abc/logs/
Group `date`    19-27   20200817
Group `jobname` 32-47   DAILY_HR_REPORT
```

I also need USA (region) from the source . Can you please help suggest.
Region will always appear after number field (44414) , which can vary in number of digits.
Ex: 123, 1234, 56789

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your regex seems quite appropriate for what you achieved. Why can't you develop the last part the same way? Is there a special obstacle which got you stuck? What did you try? How did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific about what you would allow to match as `[\W\w]+` and `.+` will cause more backtracking to fit the rest of the pattern.

Then for the region you can add a named group at the end `(?<region>[^\W_]+)`  matching one or more times any word character except an underscore.

In parts

```
(?<logdir>\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*)(?<date>(?:19|20)\d{2}(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))\/job_(?<jobname>\w+)_\d+_(?<region>[^\W_]+)_log
```

- `(?<logdir>` Group *logdir*

  - `\/(?:[^\/]+\/)*` match `/` and optionally repeat any char except `/` followed by matching the `/` again
- `)` Close group
- `(?<date>` Group *date*

  - `(?:19|20)\d{2}` Match a year starting with 19 or 20
  - `(?:0?[1-9]|1[012])` Match a month
  - `(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` Match a day
- `)`  Close group
- `\/job_` Match `/job_`
- `(?<jobname>\w+)` Group *jobname*, match 1+ word chars
- `_\d+_` Match 1+ digits between underscores
- `(?<region>[^\W_]+)` Group *region* Match 1+ occurrences of a word char except `_`
- `_log` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tmEJVT/1)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation - @The fourth bird . Works like a charm !